# Can't change component property

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular2, so there are a lot of things I dont' know yet. I created the following Component :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'game-card',
    templateUrl: 'assets/js/app/play/game-card.html',
    directives: [NgIf, ReferencesModalComponent]
})

export class GameCardComponent
{
    public showUserReferences: boolean = false;

    public showUserReferencesModal()
    {
        this.showUserReferences = true;
    }
}
```

To go with that component I have the following template :

```
<div>
    <references-modal *ngIf="showUserReferences == true"></references-modal>

    <button class="basic-link" (click)="showUserReferencesModal()">
        <small>Références</small>
    </button>
</div>
```

The problem is that the method is correctly called but the value of `this.showUserReferences` never changes... To be honest, if we print the property just after changing its value, it's good. But if we call again the method, the values didn't change...

**EDIT**

Thank everyone for your answers. I finally discovered what was the problem. I was calling my component in a NgFor loop.

```
    <div *ngFor="#results of getResults()"></div>
```

The problem was to loop on a method. I replaced getResults() with a simple array and everything is working fine now.

Comment: No need to add `NgIf,` to `directives`. It's part of `CORE_DIRECTIVES` which are globally available by default.

Comment: Seems to work fine https://plnkr.co/edit/ZPSNUI?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

> But if we call ***again*** the method, the values didn't change

```
public showUserReferencesModal()
{
    this.showUserReferences = !this.showUserReferences;
}
```

OR just   (If you don't want to call `showUserReferencesModal` method),

```
(click)="showUserReferences = !showUserReferences"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using a method :

```
<div>
    <references-modal *ngIf="showUserReferences"></references-modal>

    <button class="basic-link" (click)="showUserReferences = !showUserReferences">
        <small>Références</small>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't saw your mistake in your showUserReferencesModal method, micronyks get it.

Comment: I tested his code with a plunk and didn't find anything wrong then read his problem again and thought this could be the problem area.

Answer (score 0):

few Points to be noted here : -

- No need to add `NgIf`, to directives. It's part of `CORE_DIRECTIVES` which are globally available by default as said by @gunter
- No need to check `true` here in the *ngIf because this already accepts `true`/`false`. When `showUserReferences` is `true` this code is supposed to be work:

```
*ngIf="showUserReferences"
```

- Instead of calling method for just toggling value you can use

```
(click)="showUserReferences = !showUserReferences"
```